# How to send data back to previous page

Tags: android, file-upload

I am making a chat application In which I have provided option to upload the file on to server,issue is I want to send data to previous page.Here is what exactly what I want.
[image]

Above is my first activity when I click on upload new activity starts
[image]

Now when I click on"Click to upload"button image is uploaded and my second activity closes. I want to send the path of image uploaded  along with image name to the previous activity's text box next to send button so how should I do it.
I cannot call the activity again as it is selective chat screen from list of chat members,so I am just finishing the second activity by which my previous activity is brought to front

Please help me

Comment: You can use `startActivityForResult` from 1st activity and in second activity finish method you can pass the uri path in intent as extra parameter. see this one [3.3. Retrieving result data from a sub-activity](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should use `startActivityForResult()` to launch your child(first) `Activity`.

This provides a pipeline for sending data back to the main Activity using `setResult()`. The `setResult()` method takes an int result value and an `Intent` that is passed back to the calling `Activity`.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH",path);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

To access the returned data in the calling Activity override `onActivityResult()`. The `requestCode` corresponds to the integer passed in in the `startActivityForResult()` call, while the `resultCode` and data Intent are returned from the child(first) Activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
    case (MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // TODO Extract the path of image uploaded returned from intent
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY is keyword?
I have written it code as
  upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Messaging.this, MainActivity.class);
    //messageText.setText("uploads/");
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
    

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

  })

Comment: MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY is nothing but FIRST_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE and replace startActivityForResult(i,FIRST_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reach out for this by starting your second activity with `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` and then when you are going to finish your second activity add whatever data you want in the intent and then you will find method `onActivityResult` called. for more details check this example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to accomplish this.

The first one and the convenient one would be to use `startActivityForResult()` method in your 1st activity. And when you finish your `secondActivity` put the uri path in `intent` as a key Value pair. In first activity override `protected void onActivityResult()` method. and get the data you put in the intent.

The second way is the same start your activity as you normally start like use `startActivity(your second activity)` and override the finish method of `secondActivity` put the uri path as extra in your intent and while you finish this activity get the data in your firstActivity via overriding the `onResume()` method.

For more you can see this link [Android Intents - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

and this one [How to pass a value from one Activity to another in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android).

Hope that helps.