# Android/Java get value from other class with method

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to pass value from 1 class method to another class activity

**strong text**

```
   public class A extends Activity{
    int value;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       .
       .
       . 
     methodA();
    } 

    public void methodA(){

       if (condition){
            value =1
       }
       else if (condition){
            value =2
           }
       else{
            value =3
           }
        }

        }
        }
```

**class B**

```
Public class B extends Activity{

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       int val;
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       .
       . 
     //how do we can get val = value
    } 

}
```

Question is how can `val` from class B get the `value` from class A, will intent work for these condition?

Comment: Possibly you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options to pass values. However passing integer is not best pattern in my private opinion. I used to create class ex. call it ContainerWithData that implements **Serializable**  (may be Parcalable). I would prefer thge first one as it can be used later on by other libraries like Gson for api sending or mappers to convert.

```
Class Aa extends Activity {

   public initAndRunBeAcitvity(int parameterInt){
      ContainerWithData data = new ContainerWithData();
      data.setIntegerValue(parameterInt);
      runBe(data);
   }

   public void runBe(ContainerWithData data){
      Intent intent = new Intent(Aa.this,Be.class);
      intent.putExtra("MyBeData",data);
      startActivity(intent); 
   }

}

Class Be extends Activity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      prepareInitParameters();
   }

   private void prepareInitParameters(){
     getInitParameters();
     checkInitParameters();
   }

   private void getInitParameters(){
     ContainerWithData value = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyBeData");
     this.value = value;
   }


   private void checkInitParameters(){
      if (value==null){
               //Perform any initialization data, 
               //message or postDelayed closing of activity
       } 
   }


}

Class ContainerWithData implements Serializable {

   @Getter
   @Setter
   private Integer integerValue; 
   //can be null if not setted, 
   //so should be checked by if conditions later on controller of view logic

}
```

So proposition is to use

> getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyBData");

and

> getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyBData");
>   together with using model to pass data.

With such pattern many times I had avoid spending more time to add new values as application grows.

Comment: I think this is what im looking for let me have a try first :)

Comment: @user2930725 parcelable is better than serializing. if you are passing primitive data types there is no need for  serializing

Comment: You should always look to put serializable and not promitive data, remeber that it is simplier to extend later by addind some extra values inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent for this purpose

```
public void methodA(){

   if (condition){
        value =1
   }
   else if (condition){
        value =2
       }
   else{
        value =3
       }
      Intent intent = new Intent(this,B.class);
      intent.putExtra("key",value);
      startActivity(intent); 
    }
```

Then

```
Public class B extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   int val;
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);  
   .
```

Comment: i have already try this and it not working, it ill give out default value that is = 0 it not going to take out the value values to class B.

Comment: @user2930725 then the value is not sent properly coz `getIntExtra("key",0);` the default is 0

Answer (score 0):

When starting your activity B you can send the value with the Intent.

In A (when starting B):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("MYVALUE", val);
startActivity(intent);
```

In B:

```
val = getIntent().getIntExtra("MYVALUE");
```