# saving the edittext value to another activity on click of save actionbutton in android

Tags: android

how to save the text given to edit text, after clicking the save action button in action bar that should save to another activity.
my first activity Add.java

```
public class Add extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflate=getMenuInflater();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_add_action, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save:save();
                return true;
            case R.id.cancel:cancelnavi();
                return true;    
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void save() {
        EditText titlename;
        titlename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittitle);
        String title=titlename.getText().toString();
        if (title.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            Toast.makeText(Add.this, "Script title should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent i;
            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scripts.class);
            i.putExtra("n", titlename.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            titlename.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

It should be saved to scripts.java

```
public class Scripts extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scripts); 
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflate=getMenuInflater();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:editscript();
            break;  
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void editscript() {
        Intent editinIntent;
        editinIntent=new Intent(Scripts.this, Edit.class);
        startActivity(editinIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe , that you can find answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
public class Scripts extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_scripts); 
         getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);



        //Extract the data

         String yourTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("n");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response kelvincer it worked for my apps.

Comment: ,hi if i want edittext value to be saved as a list of items permanently should i use listview.And if i want to save large text in that item what should i use.Please help me on this. Thanks...

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html