# android integer value passing from one activity to other issue

Tags: android, android-activity, integer

i want to pass integer value from one activity to other i try to do this but value not pass please tell me right solution.

this the activity code from where i want to pass value to other activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            TotalCalories.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Total Sum", sum);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

this is the code where i want to get the value.

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int sum = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("Total Sum"));
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewname);
    textview.setText(extras.getString("Total Sum"));
```

Comment: which string you are passing value from one activty, you are not using same in next activty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this change the Totalsum in your get String

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    TotalCalories.class);
                            intent.putExtra("TotalSum", sum);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Add this inside Oncreate of new activity

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            int sum = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("TotalSum"));
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewname);
            textview.setText("Your OutPut"+sum);
```

Comment: again crashing add your Logcat message here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81701/discussion-between-mano-and-eman-ch).

Answer (score 2):

**From sender activity:**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**In receiver activity:**

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

**Note:** The 2nd parameter received `'0'`, is default value. If you don't pass any value through `intent` then it will assign `0` to the **intValue** variable.

Comment: how to display value in textview

Comment: At first create a textView object: `TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(...)`
then `tv.setText(""+intValue);`

Answer (score 1):

Use following in another activity to get integer

```
Intent i =getIntent();
int abc=  i.getIntExtra("TotalSum");
TextView textview =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewname);
textview.setText(String.valueOf(abc));
```

Comment: what should i write in the last line

Answer (score 0):

two issues in your code

1) you are not passing bundle but fetching value from bundle.

use below link 
[How to pass a value from one Activity to another in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

2)
and to get integer value

```
Intent in =getIntent();
int abc=  in.getIntExtra("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it

```
int yourInt = 0; //initialize it

yourInt = yourIntergerValue;

Intent yourActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class); 
yourActivityIntent.putExtra("yourIntKey",yourInt); 
startActivity(yourActivityIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First put the value in FirstActivity**

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourSecondActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("intValue",value);
       startActivity(intent);
```

**then,
SecondActivity get the value**

```
        Bundle exBundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        int intValue= exBundle.getInt("intValue");
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewname);
        textview.setText("Your Value is "+intValue);
```