# ANDROID: Send text to next page

Tags: android

Hi guys I dont know how to send the texts of my textview to the editText of my next page using a button to go to the next page using intent. Thanks in advance for the help. Here are my codes. :)

## ownerDetails.class

```
public class OwnerDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvCarModel, tvCarType, tvCapacity, tvFuelType, tvPlateNumber, tvPoster,tvCarPrice;
ImageView ivImage;
Button btnEdit, btnDelete;
private FunDapter<Cars> adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final Cars Cars = (Cars)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cars");

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(OwnerDetail.this));


    tvCarModel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarModel);
    tvCarType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarType);
    tvCapacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCapacity);
    tvFuelType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFuelType);
    tvPoster = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPoster);
    tvPlateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPlateNumber);
    tvCarPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCarPrice);
    ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in = new Intent(OwnerDetail.this, UpdateClick.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });


    try {
        if (Cars != null) {
            tvCarModel.setText("Car Model: "+Cars.Car_Model);
            tvCarType.setText("Car Type: "+ Cars.Car_Type);
            tvCapacity.setText("Capacity: "+Cars.Capacity);
            tvFuelType.setText("Fuel Type: "+Cars.FuelType);
            tvPlateNumber.setText("Plate Number: "+Cars.PlateNumber);
            tvPoster.setText("Posted by: " + Cars.owner);
            tvCarPrice.setText("Price: " + Cars.carPrice);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Cars.Image, ivImage);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in details " + e.toString());
    }

}

}
```

## UpdateClick.class

```
public class UpdateClick extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etCarModel;
EditText etCarType;
EditText etCapacity;
EditText etPlateNumber;
ImageView ivImg;
Spinner spFuelType;
Button btnSelectPhoto,btnUpdate;
GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
Bitmap bitmap;
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1231;
String selectedPhoto;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
            String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            selectedPhoto = photoPath;
            try {
                bitmap = com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                ivImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong while opening gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_click);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());
    spFuelType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spFuelType);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fuel_types,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spFuelType.setAdapter(adapter);
    spFuelType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(UpdateClick.this));

    etCarModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarModel);
    etCarType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarType);
    etCapacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCapacity);
    etPlateNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlateNumber);
    ivImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
    btnSelectPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);


    btnSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Save the text to a String and pass it via bundle to next activity

Comment: Intent.putExtra does the job. Spend something more than 15 seconds for googling, and you'll find an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a value from one Activity to another in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use intent send text to other page like this:

```
    String sometext = textview.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("myText", sometext);
    startActivity(i);
```

and in nextActivity use can get like this:

in onCreate()

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String getNewText = intent.getStringExtra("myText");
```

now you can set your string to any edittext.. i hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `intent.putextra()`

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button)

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
   // send text to next activity 

    intent.putExtra("text",textView.getText().toString())
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Code this in `onCreate()` method of Next activity

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);           
editText.setText(bundle.getString("text"));
```