# Display to another activity json array result from onPostExecute

Tags: java, android

How do I get the json result from onPostExecute to another activity? I was able to get the user details from the database based on the username logged in. So in my HomePageActivity there is  a button to go to profile and when I clicked on btnprofile it displays the user details on textviews in the current activity(HomePageActivity) but what I wanted to do is to get the user details and then display it to a new activity, which is in the Profile Activity. I tried using Intent but when I go to Profile Activity it displays nothing. Can you please help me? :(

Here is my HomePageActivity:

```
package com.example.androidmp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.content.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import com.example.androidmp.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.androidmp.User;
import com.example.androidmp.Poem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HomePageActivity extends Activity {


    Button btnfeed, btnprofile;
    User u = new User();
    String Username,Password,Fullname,Email,Location,Bio,uname;
    String getusername,getpw,getfn,getem,getloc,getb;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Intent i;
    Bundle bundle;
    private static final String USERNAME = "Username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "Password";
    private static final String FULLNAME = "Fullname";
    private static final String EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String BIO = "Bio";
    private static final String LOCATION = "Location";
    String s="";
    TextView fn,em,loc,b;
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "user";
    private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://192.168.1.5/webservices/mycontroller/getUser.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        u.SetUsername(intent.getStringExtra(u.username()));
        fn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        em = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        loc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getusername);
        textView.setText(u.getUsername());
        uname = u.getUsername().toString();
        //uname = textView.toString();

        //u.SetUsername(uname.toString());

        btnprofile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnprofile);
        btnfeed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfeed);

        //getem = em.getText().toString();
        //getloc = loc.getText().toString();
        //getb = b.getText().toString();

        btnprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new ProfileAsync().execute();


                Intent i = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("fullname",Fullname);
                i.putExtra("email", Email);
                i.putExtra("bio", Bio);
                i.putExtra("location", Location);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();



            }
        });

        btnfeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this,FeedActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
    }


      class ProfileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

                private Dialog loadingDialog;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomePageActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String json=null;
                    byte[] data;
                    StringBuffer buffer = null;
                    InputStream is = null;



                    try{
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", uname));

                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        Log.e("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());





                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    return json;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String json){
                    super.onPostExecute(json);

                    loadingDialog.dismiss();

                    try
                    {
                    jsonobject = new JSONObject(json);
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("user");
                    JSONObject jb= jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
                    //Username = jb.getString("Username");
                    //Password = jb.getString("Password");
                    Fullname = jb.getString("Fullname");
                    Email = jb.getString("Email");
                    Bio = jb.getString("Bio");
                    Location = jb.getString("Location");


                    fn.setText(Fullname);
                    em.setText(Email);
                    loc.setText(Location);
                    b.setText(Bio);



                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            }//end of asynctask






}
```

Here is my ProfileActivity:

```
package com.example.androidmp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.content.*;
import com.example.androidmp.User;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {


    Button btncreate;
    private TextView _username,_password,_fullname,_Email,_bio,_location;
    User u = new User();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profileview);

        //_username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._username);
        //_password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._password);
        _fullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._fullname);
        _Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._Email);
        _bio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._bio);
        _location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._location);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        u.SetUsername(i.getStringExtra(u.username()));
        _username.setText(u.getUsername());




        String displayfullname = i.getExtras().getString("fullname");
        String displayemail = i.getExtras().getString("email");
        String displaybio = i.getExtras().getString("bio");
        String displaylocation = i.getExtras().getString("location");


        _fullname.setText(displayfullname);
       _Email.setText(displayemail);
        _bio.setText(displaybio);
       _location.setText(displaylocation);



    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because new activity starts before async task is completed. Just call function for start new activity in `onPostExecute()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass values after fetching the details. Is the settext working properly? then you can give the intent at that scope, in the onPostexecute method. Look before doing this.[Look this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: Thank you sir! I put Intent in the onPostExecute method and it's now working!

Comment: Glad you made it :)