# Is there any way to handle button click in another activity where it is not defined?

Tags: android

e.g.
Activity 1
Button b = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.button);
// i want b.setOnClickListener in Activity2 
Activity 2
b.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea even if it is basically possible. What are you trying to achive by this approach?

Comment: i want to get callback in another activity that  button is clicked and want to perform some operation. Do u have any idea sir ?

Comment: But if you click a Button in one Activity then the other Activity may not even exist (can be destroyed e.g. if the device is low on memory)

Comment: if i don't finish 1st activity and open second one then how it will work >

Comment: Then you should have the OnClickListener in the same Activity where the Button is. And then you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: No bro. is there any possibility to get button's callback in activity2.

Comment: None that I can recommend.

Comment: For a callback like use case you may want to use this approach. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: You can use EventBus instead of callback between two activity.