# Android Studio (send parameter from activity to another activity)

Tags: java, android

Given two activities, MainActivity and DetailActivity, what is the necessary code to start the DetailActivity from MainActivity and send 2 parameters, one string and the other an integer, and how can you access the parameters in the newly started activity?

Comment: Can you explain to readers what you have discovered, by searching the internet and reading the manual?

Comment: This is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android#:~:text=Standard%20way%20of%20passing%20data%20from%20one%20activity%20to%20another%3A&text=putString(%E2%80%9CONE%E2%80%9D%2C%20one,getExtra()%20to%20get%20data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: Did you use putExtra and getExtra?

Comment: Please don't invalidate your question by mutilating it. If you want to thank people and signal that your question has been answered, accept the answer that most helped you. I have rolled back your edit. I recommend you familiarize yourself with how Stack Overflow works by taking the tour and reading the help center.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MY_STRING", "hello");
intent.putExtra("MY_INT", 42);
startActivity(intent);
```

And to retrieve it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("MY_STRING");
    int myInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("MY_INT", 0); // 0 = default value

    // your code
}
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/7292958

Answer (score 0):

First you need  to create  a new activity.
Then create an Intent in the main activity from where you want to move to the  next one  :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
```

then send the parameters you want to send using:

```
      intent.putExtra("name",name);
       intent.putExtra("age",age);
```

then start the activity

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Go the the detailActivity and put this:

```
    Intent intent=getIntent();
            String name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
Integer age=intent.getStringExtra("age");
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "John");
intent.putExtra("age", 22);

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
String suburb = intent.getStringExtra("name");
Integer age = intent.getIntExtra("age");

Answer (score 0):

i'm suggest you to use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)
send data to another activity just like this

```
startActivity<DetailActivity>(
        "string" to "stringData",
        "int" to 0
    )
```

with this format "params" to "value"
value can use variable, and you not need to add data type
and get the data use intent